# What does dmesg say about my bootable USB?

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 57.31 GiB, 61530439680 bytes, 120176640 sectors
Disk model:  SanDisk 3.2Gen1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5b0f827a

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       64 3276799 3276736  1.6G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
```

How do I make out from this output that this USB is bootable or not?

What other output should I produce here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your USB device is bootable as the asterisk ***** under the Boot column in the last line of the results of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` indicates.

```
Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       64 3276799 3276736  1.6G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
```